# JavaFX Event Handler No longer working

Tags: javafx, event-handling

In My code I created an event handler that originally worked; however after adding more code it stopped working so I restored to before my changes and it still won't work. Is there something that I have done wrong? Also, I am using eclipse if that is helpful in determining a cause.

Main.java:
    package application;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.InputEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


public class Main extends Application {
    public Parent root;
    public ChessUtil chess = new ChessUtil();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Chess.fxml"));
            Node peice;
            for(int x = 0; x < 16 ;x++)
            {
                peice = root.lookup("#" + chess.whiteID[x]);
                peice.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, peiceClick);
                peice = root.lookup("#" + chess.blackID[x]);
                peice.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, peiceClick);
            }
            disablePeicesToggle(chess.blackID, true);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,740,740);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    EventHandler peiceClick = new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {
        public void handle(InputEvent event) {
            String id = ((Node) event.getSource()).getId();
            ArrayList<String> moves = chess.findPeiceMoves(id);
            System.out.println(moves.size());
            if(moves.size() > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(moves);
            }
            System.out.println("Handling event " + event.getEventType()); 
            event.consume();
        }
     };
    public void disablePeicesToggle(String[] idSet, boolean disable)
    {
        Node peice;
        for(int x = 0; x < 16 ;x++)
        {
            peice = root.lookup("#" + idSet[x]);
            peice.setDisable(disable);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Chess.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="740.0" prefWidth="740.0" stylesheets="@application/application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane id="chessboard" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="720.0" stylesheets="@application/application.css" />
      <AnchorPane id="board-spaces" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0">
         <children>
            <Region id="b7" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bRook" />
            <Region id="b3" layoutX="160.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bBishop" />
            <Region id="b5" layoutX="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bKnight" />
            <Region id="b2" layoutX="240.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bQueen" />
            <Region id="b1" layoutX="320.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bKing" />
            <Region id="b4" layoutX="400.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bBishop" />
            <Region id="b6" layoutX="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bKnight" />
            <Region id="b8" layoutX="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bRook" />
            <Region id="b12" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b10" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b13" layoutX="320.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b16" layoutX="560.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b9" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b15" layoutX="480.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b11" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="b14" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bPawn" />
            <Region id="w3" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wBishop" />
            <Region id="w12" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w10" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w5" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wKnight" />
            <Region id="w7" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wRook" />
            <Region id="w14" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w1" layoutX="320.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wKing" />
            <Region id="w2" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wQueen" />
            <Region id="w6" layoutX="480.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wKnight" />
            <Region id="w13" layoutX="320.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w16" layoutX="560.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w9" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w15" layoutX="480.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w11" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="480.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wPawn" />
            <Region id="w8" layoutX="560.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wRook" />
            <Region id="w4" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="wBishop" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
         <AnchorPane id="board-overlay" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Update: I have put my code in a GitHub repo.
 Full Source code is at github.com/stitch366/chess/tree/master/chess.

Comment: No. What I'm looking up is already in the fxml

Comment: Full Source code is at https://github.com/stitch366/chess/tree/master/chess. Also I am Loading an FXML File, and Ids have been set in the FXML file. There is no controller Because I am not using a custom component or displaying data.

Comment: I put my Code on GitHub meaning that you can go look at it including the FXML; Adding the FXML would make the way longer than it already is. Also, A controller won't work for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed an anchor pane (with id `board-overlay`) on top of all the other components in the main layout. It appears "on top" (in Z-order) because you placed it there last. When the user clicks on the board, since that node is on top, it receives the mouse event; thus none of the `Region`s representing pieces ever receive mouse events and invoke the listener.

It's not clear why you need that overlay: obviously if you just remove it everything will work. If you need it for other reasons, you can stop it intercepting mouse events by setting `mouseTransparent="true"` in the FXML:

```xml
<AnchorPane id="board-overlay" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="60.0" 
    prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0" mouseTransparent="true"/>
```

Possibly off-topic:

The structure of your application is ***very strongly not recommended***. The purpose of the `Application` subclass is to manage application life cycle: i.e. to start up the application (the `start(...)` method) and to cleanly shut it down, if needed (the `stop()` method). It is not the responsibility of the application class to manage user events: that is the explicit purpose of a controller class. I ***strongly*** recommend refactoring this so that your event handling is managed in a controller. One reason (the main reason) is that your application becomes much more flexible by doing this. (E.g. if you wanted to have an application where multiple games were displayed in different tabs, it would be very hard to refactor from where you are now. Using a controller to manage the event handling for each FXML it would be very easy.) Another reason is that using lookups is very fragile: typically it relies on CSS having been applied to the scene graph, which does not happen by default until the first time the scene is actually rendered to the screen. Here it seems it works ok, probably because the CSS ids are set explicitly, but there really is no guarantee this will work in future releases of JavaFX.

I would refactor your application class so that it does nothing more that start up the app (which is its responsibility):

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Chess.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,740,740);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and move the event handling to a controller class:

```
package application;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root ;

    private ChessUtil chess = new ChessUtil();

    @FXML
    private void click(MouseEvent event) {
        String id = ((Node) event.getSource()).getId();
        ArrayList<String> moves = chess.findPeiceMoves(id);
        System.out.println(moves.size());
        if(moves.size() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(moves);
        }
        System.out.println("Handling event " + event.getEventType()); 
        event.consume();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        disablePeicesToggle(chess.blackID, true);
    }


    public void disablePeicesToggle(String[] idSet, boolean disable)
    {
        Node peice;
        for(int x = 0; x < 16 ;x++)
        {
            peice = root.lookup("#" + idSet[x]);
            peice.setDisable(disable);
        }

    }
}
```

Then just update the FXML to reference the root node, and map each `Region` representing a piece to the event handler method in the controller:

```xml
<AnchorPane prefHeight="740.0" prefWidth="740.0" stylesheets="@application/application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="application.Controller" fx:id="root">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane id="chessboard" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="720.0" stylesheets="@application/application.css"/>
      <AnchorPane id="board-spaces" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0">
         <children>
            <Region id="b7" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bRook" onMouseClicked="#click" />
            <Region id="b3" layoutX="160.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bBishop" onMouseClicked="#click" />
            <Region id="b5" layoutX="80.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="bKnight" onMouseClicked="#click" />

            <!-- etc... -->
         </children></AnchorPane>
         <AnchorPane id="board-overlay" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="60.0" 
             prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="640.0" mouseTransparent="true"/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```